# Gap In Borders In IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, twitter-bootstrap, border

I am having problems with borders in IE as seen [here](http://slotted.co/). Open this page n IE 9 and you will notice artifacts around the left corners of the Welcome box.  They appear to jump around as you move the mouse.

I change to any earlier Document Mode, which removes the radius, and I can see more clearly what is happening.  There are well-defined gaps on the top and bottom borders at the left corners.

I removed all styles except the border itself (in F12 tools).  The gaps remain.  What is causing this?

By the way, the site uses Twitter Bootstrap.  I'm not sure that tells you anything important.  When I turn off JS, the gaps remain as well.

Comment: The link to your page isn't working.

Comment: jsfiddle.net live simplified demo would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "fixed" this by removing rounded corners in IE.  Here's how I did that.

In all pages:

```
<!--[if IE]><html class="ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html class="not-ie"><!--<![endif]-->
```

In CSS:

```
.ie * {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

This sucks, and it's not right, but it's good enough for me right now.